# Creating map tip with pictures stored in relative path

Tags: qgis, html, maptips

I have created a QGIS 3.34 project in this directory: "C:/MyProject". Alongside with the QGIS project file there is a folder containing some georeferenced pictures I want to show on my QGIS project. Its directory would be: "C:/MyProject/MyPictures".

In the project, such images were imported by creating a geopackage saved in "C:/MyProject" as well. Then, I want to display such images when the cursor is placed over a certain point, like in the picture below:

[image]

For that, I double-clicked on my pictures layer, went to display and inserted the following HTML code:

`<img src="file:///[% photo %]" width="375" height="250">`,

where "[% photo %]" refers to the absolute path of each picture.

As long as the project is in "C:/MyProject", everything behaves correctly. However, my intention is to save such a project in more than one computer. When I copy the "MyProject" folder to another computer and run QGIS from it, I see that the pictures are gone:

[image]

I would like to link all those pictures to the project by making QGIS refer to them just by using a relative path like this: 'MyPictures/[filename]', but I don't know how to do this.

By writing the following code,

[image]

the image is not displayed yet. In this case, the subfolder where the pictures are is called "Camera_GeoTagged". I followed the steps that @eurojam provided, but my [% filename %] value refers just to the filename itself, without providing any extension, in this case '.jpg'. If I remove the '.jpg' characters from the HTML code I still get the same preview with the image not found.

Is there a way to import the georeferenced pictured to QGIS with a filename that clearly shows its extension?

Answer (score 6):

you can put the images in a subfolder below your project and then you can refer to the images as a relative path...in the example below I have a field `image`storing the file name, which are located in a subfolder `/photos`. For the map tips I use HTML map tips with the following form:

```
<img src="file:///photos/[% image %]"  width="200"></img>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've applied your method but the fact that my filenames don't contain the image extension doesn't let me do that. So I can't see the pictures appear yet. I've edited my post by introducing these facts. Do you know how could I proceed now?

Comment: Your expression should work, I've tried it the same way like you without any problems...: <img src="file:///photos/[% filename %].jpg"  width="200"></img>

Comment: That's strange... Perhaps it's a settings issue. Do you think it has to do with the Attribute Table? Besides, I imported the images by going to the Processing Toolbox panel on the right hand side > Vector creation > Import geotagged pictures. Is this the way you would recommend me to import them? Perhaps that's causing the error.

Comment: I did it the same way, then I added an new textfield "image" with the fieldcalaculator: "filename" || '.jpg' and used this one in the expression above...

Comment: I also did that but still getting the same error. I set the new textfield as string, but it didn't work. Have you got any ideas why it might be not working in my case?

Comment: make sure that your path is a subfolder of the projectfolder and be aware that QGIS is case sensitive, so if there are different upper and lower cases in the path or filenames...it won't work

Comment: I meet all those requirements, but it still doesn't work. Thank you anyway.